# jQuery: Create an array from JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have a JSON like this:

```
{
  "default": [
    [
      1325876000000,
      0
    ],
    [
      1325876000000,
      0
    ],
    [
      1325876000000,
      0
    ],
    [
      1325876000000,
      0
    ]
  ],
  "direct": [
    [
      1328196800000,
      0
    ],
    [
      1328196800000,
      100
    ],
    [
      1328196800000,
      0
    ],
    [
      1328196800000,
      0
    ]
  ],
  "Sales": [
    [
      1330517600000,
      0
    ],
    [
      1330517600000,
      0
    ],
    [
      1330517600000,
      90
    ],
    [
      1330517600000,
      0
    ]
  ],
  "Support": [
    [
      1332838400000,
      0
    ],
    [
      1332838400000,
      0
    ],
    [
      1332838400000,
      0
    ],
    [
      1332838400000,
      0
    ]
  ]
}
```

I want to generate array contains the name of each item and the first value of the corresponing array. the result should be like this:

```
ticks = [["default", 1325876000000],["direct", 1328196800000],["Sales", 1330517600000],["Support", 1332838400000]]
```

#### the names like default, direct, sales, support

are dynamic so I can't do `jsondata.support`

#### what I tried

```
ticks = []
for key in jsondata{
    arraynew = [];
    arraynew.push(key)
}
```

but I don't know how to push the values?

Help please.

Comment: EDIT: arraynew.push(jsondata[key][0][0])

Comment: Why put arraynew = []; inside the loop?

Comment: @LuisMasuelli that push the whole array, i just need the first value

Comment: @GôTô to take all the dynamic data.

Comment: @user2208349 Sorry I don't get it. Won't it empty arraynew for each key?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to access the sub-array.

```
var ticks = [];
for (var key in jsondata) {
  ticks.push( [ key, jsondata[key][0][0] ] );
}
```

The expression `jsondata[key]` gets you the outer array corresponding to each key. Then, `jsondata[key][0]` gets you the first of the sub-arrays, and adding the final `[0]` to that gets you the first value in the first sub-array.

Note that you're not guaranteed to get the keys back in any particular order.

Comment: +1 It works. amazing. thanks. will accept it once the system allows